# Is it possible to get all available metrics for an Azure resource type?

Tags: c#, azure, api

I have written code that retrieves metric definitions for each resource type ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/list#uri-parameters)) but as it turns out you can also specify a metric namespace. I am now confused as to how I can retrieve all metric definition for each resource.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am now confused as to how I can retrieve all metric definition for each resource.

You just need to call this REST API without the `metricnamespace` parameter, it will return all the metric definitions, when the `resourceUri` is provided, the `metricnamespace` is decided.

For example, the `resourceUri` is `/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/joystoragev2`, then the `metricnamespace` is `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts`.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01
```

For the supported metrics for the metric namespaces, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported).